# Radio buttons Navigation by KeyBoard

Tags: c#, winforms

I have 3 radio buttons on my WinForm.

I would like to give the user the option to navigate between them also by keyboard.
Is there a way to enable it?

I understand I have to use this code:

```
 if (e.KeyChar==Convert.ToChar(Keys.Down))
```

But how do I know which single radio button I have to set as checked?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest solution is to use keyboard shortcuts. This entails prefixing one character in each RadioButton's text with the & character.

For example if the text of your radio button is "&Big option" then the user can select this option by pressing the [ALT] and B keys at the same time.

Additionally, once one of the radio buttons has the focus you can navigate between them by using the up and down arrows. In general, the user can navigate between controls by using the [Tab] key. In VS 2010 the tab order may be modified by selecting the View->Tab Order menu item.

The same keyboard shortcut trick works for many other controls. For example if you have a TextBox control preceded by a label control you can prefix a letter in the Label control with &. Now since the Label (by default) can't take the focus, when the user uses the Label's keyboard shortcut, the focus will move to the next control in the Tab Order i.e. the TextBox.

If you want a control to be skipped when using the [Tab] key set its TabStop property to False.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed reply. You say I can automatically navigate when one of them is focused, but the navigation is also on other controls on my WinForm. That's why I would like to use the code I've posted. Any ideas?

Comment: I don't follow. Can you give a specific example of something that's not working for you?

Comment: What kind of example- I did not code it since I don't know how to do it. The default navigation fails as mentioned. Tnx

Comment: I can't help you unless you specify what fails. 'Default navigation fails' gives me no information. WinForms supports keyboard navigation out of the box so if it's not working there's something missing in your Form. By default the [Tab] key navigates between controls and once you hit the first RadioButton in a group of RadioButtons you can use the up/down arrows to cycle between them. You can then use [Tab] at any time to leave the Radiobutton group. What exactly does not work?

Comment: When I navigate I cannot loop on the radiobuttons on their serial order. Secondly, navigation occures on buttons which also exist on the same forum. Thank you so much.

Comment: Oh, you reached the point! how can I set the other controls which are not radio buttons, to have no TabIndex value?

Comment: Set their TabStop property to false. Then they'll be skipped. Updated answer - see last paragraph.

Comment: Almost perfect!  That's exactly what I mean, but when navigating and reaching the index of button control, the button is not focused as I set TabStop to false, but the navigation is waiting at the recent spot and does not continue. Can we avoid it?

Comment: Are you sure? Focus should move on to the next control. If there is no next control then the focus should move back to the first focusable control on your Form.

Comment: Yes it is. Still delayed when managing the button index. Even setting its tab index to 5000 does not change the fact. Any ideas?

Comment: No idea. This is a completely different issue to the original question posted. I suggest raising a new question so that other users of this site will be able to reference it in the future. And so that you'll get fresh eyes looking at this particular issue.